# How to make visible long lat coordinates after click to map and make visible until next click?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, openlayers, getelementbyid

from [this](https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch09-taking-control-of-controls/example-03.html) code for make visible long lat coordinate after moving the mouse over the map. And I rewrite to HTML page with newest OpenLayers version.

I would like to **show this long lat coordinates after click to some place in map**, not after move mouse on map as in the code. And **make visible last coordinate until someone click** to next place, nothing. I don't want the coordinates to disappear right away as in code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="myposition"></div>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var osm_default = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [osm_default],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.transform([-1.81185, 52.443141], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
          zoom: 6
        })
      });

      var mousePosition = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(2),
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        target: document.getElementById('myposition'),
        innerHTML: '&nbsp;'
      });

      map.addControl(mousePosition);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`singleclick`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_MapBrowserEvent-MapBrowserEvent.html#event:singleclick) or [`click`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_MapBrowserEvent-MapBrowserEvent.html#event:click) event on your map:

```js
map.on('singleclick', event => { 
  const coordinate = ol.proj.toLonLat(event.coordinate);
  const innerText = `Lon: ${coordinate[0].toFixed(4)}, Lat: ${coordinate[1].toFixed(4)}`;

  document.getElementById('myposition').innerText = innerText;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this.